# Closed-form formula for $u(t):= \mathbb E[h(X_1)h(tX_1+(1-t^2)^{1/2} X_2)]$, where $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_d)$ is uniform on sphere and $h(x):=(x+c)^k$

Tags: probability, integration, special-functions, spherical-coordinates, geometric-probability

Fix $c \in \mathbb R$ and an integer $k \ge 0$, and consider the function $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $h(x) := (x+c)^k$. Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_d)$ be uniformly-distributed on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{d}$ in $\mathbb R^d$, and consider the function $u:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by

$$
u(t) := \mathbb E[h(X_1)h(tX_1+(1-t^2)^{1/2} X_2)].
$$

> **Question.**
> *Is there a closed-form formula (perhaps in terms of special functions) which gives the value of $u(t)$ for all $t \in [-1,1]$ ?*

**Observation.** Let $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Becuase the Wasserstein distance between $X_1$ and $Z$ is of order $\mathcal O(1/d)$ (see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/401444/78539)), in the limit $d \to \infty$, we have
$$
u(0) = \mathbb E[h(X_1)^2] = \mathbb E[(X_1+c)^{2k}] \to \mathbb E[(Z+c)^{2k}],
$$
and we recognize the rightmost term as the $2k$th moment of $N(c,1)$.